# Firefox extension development sqlite

Tags: sqlite, firefox-addon-sdk

using Builder online tool 
https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/
to build and test my extension 
now that I want to store data locally I'm following this tutorial 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage
but the code snippets are not working for me 
Should I be developing them locally using the classic SDK or is there a way to add SQLite support to the Add-on builder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add-on SDK is sandboxed by default and doesn't provide direct access to XPCOM. To use XPCOM objects you need to [break out of the sandbox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html):

```js
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
var {Services} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var {FileUtils} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["my_db_file_name.sqlite"]);
var mDBConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
```

Note that `Components` stays undefined - use `Cc` instead of `Components.classes`, `Ci` instead of `Components.interfaces` and `Cu` instead of `Components.utils`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple JS wrapper: https://github.com/julianceballos/sqlite-jetpack